# get the server's hostnme (not the request's hostname)

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, fastify

in a simple server like that, is there a way to get the server's hostname?

```
  let app = express()
  server.listen(3000, () => {
    let serverHostName = '???'
  });
```

note that, this is different than something like `req.headers.hostname` as `req` is not defined here

I'm looking for something like `server.hostname` such as the function that is exposed by Fastify

```
fastifyApp.server.address()
```